# Conditional formatting in MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I am trying to write an expression within the conditional formatting module of MSAccess to allow me to format a field/control on a form based on the value of another field coming from the same record. Is it possible?  At present I would like the field XXX on on my form to change font colours when the underlying field "OverallObjectivesStatus2" from the table "tblProjectMasterList" has a value of "other"...   The expression that I built is:

```
[tblProjectMasterList]![OverallObjectiveStatus2]="other"
```

but it doesnt seem to be working.
Am I missing something?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the name of the table (`[tblProjectMasterList]`) use the name of the form.